# Why is my storage partition xxGB, when Disk Utility, and Gparted say otherwise?

Tags: 11.04, partitioning, gparted

I created an **ext4** partition to back-up my files to, and partitioned it for 102GB in **Gparted** using a live USB. After I booted into Ubuntu, I opened **Disk Utility**, and it said that the partition was actually 108GB. Confused, I opened the mounted partition in **Nautilus**, and it said the partition was only 98GB.

Which is correct? Did I partition it wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I never can get the Numbers straight, but i think it can be summarized as  having to do with one using '**GiB**' vs the other using '**GB**'

I guess you could think of it in a way akin to the Metric system vs the Non-metric sytem.

A quick snippit from wikipedia. http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gibibyte

The gibibyte is a standards-based binary multiple (prefix gibi, symbol Gi) of the byte, a unit of digital information storage. The gibibyte unit symbol is **GiB**.[1](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gibibyte)

```
**1 gibibyte =** 230 bytes = 1073741824bytes = 1024 mebibytes
```

The gibibyte is closely related to the gigabyte, which is defined as 109 bytes = 1000000000bytes, but has been used as a synonym for gibibyte in some contexts (see binary prefix.) In terms of standard gigabytes, 1GiB ≈ 1.074GB.

You often see people confused about the size of the Ubuntu ISO files, the size listed on a web site or ftp server seems to be 'bigger' then a 700mb due to how different systems use  GiB or GB.

Comment: That would make sense, as I remember seeing MiB when resizing the partition.

Answer (score 2):

If I remember correctly, Nautilus as switched to using base-10 representations of data (rather than the actual base-two conversion) whereby `1GB` equals `1,000,000,000 bytes` instead of `1,073,741,824 bytes`.

This doesn't explain the difference between gparted and whatever the disk actually is though.